# How to use a Multidimensional List as a Parameter for a Maven Plugin

Tags: arrays, list, maven, plugins, multidimensional-array

I'm currently developing a Maven Plugin and have a little issue using the possibility of parameters.

What I want to achieve is that an entry in the Maven Projects POM that uses my plugin (like this):

```
<configuration>
 <values>
    <value>
        <valueList>
            <thing1>test1</thing1>
            <thing2>something.xml</thing2>
            <thing3>asdf</thing3>
        </valueList>
    </value>
    <value>
        <valueList>
            <thing1>test2</thing1>
            <thing2>somethingelse.xml</thing2>
            <thing3>asdf</thing3>
        </valueList>
    </value>
 </values>
</configuration>
```

leads to a list Object of the name Values containing list elements with the values thing1,thing2,thing3 etc.

What I tried was adding this to my code:

```
/**
* @parameter 
*/
private List<String> valueList;

/**
* @parameter 
*/
private List<List> values;
```

But when I try to run it like this I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project *myproject*:
failed to get report for *myplugin*:
Unable to parse configuration of mojo *myplugin*:startReport for parameter Values:
Cannot determine child type: *myplugin*.ValueList -> [Help 1]
```

So my question is:

How can I use a Multidimensional List as a parameter for my plugin or are there any other ways to get the result I want to achieve?

//***_*__**
EDIT
I need the Strings from valueList for an Object in my Project.
This Objects Constructor needs three Strings. Each Object should (if possible) be stored into an Array.
The POM should then look like this:

```
<arrayOfObjects>
    <arrayOfObject>
        <Object>
            <value1> one </value1>
            <value2> two </value2>
            <value3> three </value3>
        </Object>
        <Object>
            <value1> uno </value1>
            <value2> dos </value2>
            <value3> tres </value3>
        </Object>
    </arrayOfObject>
</arrayOfObjects>
```

This should then generate an "arrayOfObjects" with two Objects in it.
//***_*__**

Comment: First i would say that your definition `private List<List> Values;` is not correct cause i would expect things like `private List<List<String>> values;`?

Comment: You are right. I changed that! But sadly the same error still occures :(

Comment: I would suggest to create a separate class which contains those lists and it will work see [also the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects).

Comment: That is one good solution...
But I have one problem:
I need the elements in the valueList Element to initalise another Object. Do you think it would be possible to map the input directly to this object and save the object in the "values"-array?

For example:


<values>


 <value>


  <object>


   <objectValue/>


  </object>


 </value>


</values>

Comment: Can you show an example ? Apart from that your constructor of the class should do the work.

Comment: I edited my question. Was this what you meant by example?